# Add Subject header to server.sendmail() in Python

Tags: python, email, smtp

I'm writing a python script to send emails from the terminal. In the mail which I currently send, it is without a subject. How do we add a subject to this email?

My current code:

```
    import smtplib

    msg = """From: hello@hello.com
    To: hi@hi.com\n
    Here's my message!\nIt is lovely!
    """

    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.example.com', port=465)
    server.set_debuglevel(1)
    server.ehlo
    server.login('examplelogin', 'examplepassword')
    server.sendmail('me@me.com', ['anyone@anyone.com '], msg)
    server.quit()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put the `subject` in the header of the message.

Example -

```
import smtplib

msg = """From: hello@hello.com
To: hi@hi.com\n
Subject: <Subject goes here>\n
Here's my message!\nIt is lovely!
"""

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.example.com', port=465)
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.ehlo
server.login('examplelogin', 'examplepassword')
server.sendmail('me@me.com', ['anyone@anyone.com '], msg)
server.quit()
```

Comment: That did not work. A slight modification of your response did. The placement of \n made the difference. The right code is:
From: hello@hello.com
To: hi@hi.com
Subject: <Subject goes here>\n

Though, Thank you for making the relevant suggestion. :)

Comment: oh ok , yea updated the answer, though ideally spaces newlines should get read correctly in multiline strings

Comment: Would also advice you to accept answers for all your questions, if they helped you satisfactorily, would help the community.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use MIMEMultipart()

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'EMAIL_USER'
msg['To'] = 'EMAIL_TO_SEND'
msg['Subject'] = 'SUBJECT'

body = 'YOUR TEXT'
msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))

text = msg.as_string()
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.starttls()
server.login('email','password')
server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,text)
server.quit()
```

Hope this works!!!

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode' for `text = msg.as_string()`

Answer (score 1):

```
import smtp

def send_email(SENDER_EMAIL,PASSWORD,RECEIVER_MAIL,SUBJECT,MESSAGE):
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
#specify server and port as per your requirement
        server.starttls()
        server.login(SENDER_EMAIL,PASSWORD)
        message = """From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s""" % (SENDER_EMAIL, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, MESSAGE)
        server.sendmail(SENDER_EMAIL,TO,message)
        server.quit()
        print 'successfully sent the mail'
    except:
        print "failed to send mail"
send_email("sender@gmail.com","Password","receiver@gmail.com","SUBJECT","MESSAGE")
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the subject you missed. Those things can easily be avoided by using some API (such as yagmail) rather than the headers style.

I believe [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail) (disclaimer: I'm the maintainer) can be of great help to you, since it provides an easy API.

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP('hello@gmail.com', 'yourpassword')
yag.send(to = 'hi@hi.com', subject ='Your subject', contents = 'Some message text')
```

That's only three lines indeed.

Install with `pip install yagmail` or `pip3 install yagmail` for Python 3.

More info at [github](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail).

Comment: @user248884 What is the domain you will use? You can use `yagmail.SMTP('hello@domain.com', 'password', host = "YOUR HOST", port = "YOUR PORT")`